# Factor the two polynomials into a product of irreducible elements of $\mathbb{Q}[x]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, factoring, irreducible-polynomials, rational-numbers

I need to find a factorization of both $f_{1}=2x^{2}+4x+6$ and $f_{2}=2x^{2}+4x-6$ into a product of irreducible elements of $\mathbb{Q}[x]$.

I already was able to do so in the case of $\mathbb{Z}[x]$:

- $f_{1}=2(x^{2}+2x+3)$
- $f_{2}=2(x-(-3))(x-1)$

Note that for $f_{1}$, $x^{2}+2x+3$ has no rational roots (I tested each of the possible combinations of $\frac{p}{q}$ where the possibilities for $p$ are $\pm 1$, $\pm 3$ and the possibilities for $q$ are $\pm 1$.

I was wondering, therefore, how factoring these polynomials over $\mathbb{Q}$ would be different (and I guess, essentially, how it would proceed)? Especially in light of the fact that all integers are rational, no nonintegral rationals came up as I was factoring over the integers, and the result that states that a polynomial is irreducible over $\mathbb{Z}$ iff it is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$.

Thanks in advance for your time and patience.

Comment: $2$ is a unit in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$, hence it is not irreducible.

Comment: As you said, if you have a monic polynomial, factoring over $\mathbb{Z}$ is no different from factoring over $\mathbb{Q}$, due to the theorem.

Comment: @SahibaArora you're right! So, how would I take care of that? Don't factor them out and just jump right into rational roots theorem?

Comment: @SahibaArora but, I didn't think that mattered.

Comment: @JoeJohnson126 but what about $2$ being a unit in $\mathbb{Q}$, like Sahiba said? Would that make it different?

Comment: @ALannister You said you want to factor it into product of irreducible elements of $\mathbb{Q}[x]. 2$ is not an irreducible so this factorization won't work.

Comment: A polynomial is irreducible if it is not constant and cannot be factored into two non-constant polynomials. Once you factor out $2$, you cannot factor any further by the theorem. So, your polynomial is irreducible in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$.

Comment: There seems to be some disagreement. @SahibaArora how would you factor them then, if not like this?

Comment: Both (2x+6)(x-1) and (x+3)(2x-2) are factorizations into irreducibles over Q. It is a bit pedantic to disallow the factorization 2(x+3)(x-1), the point is just to keep in mind 2 is one of the irreducible factors over Z but is just a unit over Q.

Comment: @JoeJohnson126 The question is not whether it is irreducible. It is to factor it as product of irreducibles. This is why you can't factor out $2$ as it is not irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}[x]$.

Comment: @SahibaArora Yes. My point is that, you factor out the $2$, then try to factor the monic you get in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$.  If that is not possible, then your original polynomial must be irreducible.